# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal, Does not Create and Write to File

Tags: python, file

I am trying to create a file in APPDATA\Roaming Directory and then write some text to the File.
Its a Text file and hence does not work as its supposed to

I am getting This as Error

```
C:\pytut>python appdatapath.py
  File "appdatapath.py", line 4
    file = path + "\" + 'keys.txt'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

what can I say is possibly wrong? My codes Looks like this below

```
import os

path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
file = path + "\" + 'keys.txt'

with open(file,'w') as f:
     data = 'Hello Jasmine!'
     f.write(data)
print('Done!')
```

Kindly assist where I got it wrong. Started Python some few days ago.

Comment: \ is a escape sequence. change \ to \\

Comment: Chee thanks!! Its fine now

Answer (score 0):

You better use [os.path.join()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/#:%7E:text=os.-,path.,except%20the%20last%20path%20component.) function

```
import os.path
path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
file = os.path.join(path,'keys.txt')
```

Comment: @Evans - An advantage of using `os.path.join` is thats it’s cross-platform portable, meaning you (the developer) does not need to worry about which path separator to use, and no need to escape.  It’s a solid, robust solution.